# Does okhttp enforce any sort of limit on the size of a request body?

Tags: okhttp

I've looked through the okhttp documentation looking for an answer to this question, but have come up empty so far.   Does the okhttp library have an enforceable limit on the size of a request body?  I'm using version 4.9.1 in case that matters.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no limit. Practically speaking you'll want to choose a size that can be transmitted in a minute or less, otherwise timeouts get difficult and you'll waste work if things fail and need to be restarted.